# How to get the text enclosed within a tag, which contains multiple sub-tags, with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape a webpage which has the following tag:

```
  <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="https://documents.google.com/" alt="" width="60" height="30" />
            <br />
            Pick me please.

        <p> Do not pick me please! </p>

        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
```

I want to scrape the "pick me please" string but don't want to scrape the "Do not pick me please!" string. Any idea how?

EDIT : I would appreciate a more generic solution, where I always wish to get the text under a particular tag, which is not inside any sub-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

A more "generic" solution to `find()` the non empty `text node` in the `div`:

```
parent = soup.select_one('div')
parent.find(text=lambda text: text and text.strip(), recursive=False).strip()
```

---

To get the text node use `previous_sibling` and to avoid spaces,... `strip()` the result.

```
soup.select_one('div p').previous_sibling.strip()
```

or use `get_text()` and `strip`:

```
soup.select_one('div').get_text('|', strip=True).split('|')[0]
```

**Minimal example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="https://documents.google.com/" alt="" width="60" height="30" />
            <br />
            Pick me please.

        <p> Do not pick me please! </p>

        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

soup.select_one('div p').previous_sibling.strip()
```

**Output**

> Pick me please.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate your solution. Could there be a more 'generic' solution to this problem? If I always wish to get the text under a particular tag, which is not inside any sub-tags?

Comment: @IntoAbhi : Take a look, added a more "generic" solution, that should cover your requirements - Does it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what solves the problem. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `get_text()` method.  It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string. Here i used regular expression `re.compile` to get the text.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= """<div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="https://documents.google.com/" alt="" width="60" height="30" />
            <br />
            Pick me please.

        <p> Do not pick me please! </p>

        <br />
        <br />
    </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find(text=re.compile("Pick me please.")).strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a `<br>` tag, then call the `find_next()` method which will return the first match.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('div br').find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
Pick me please.
```